# Proxy permission denied when executing wget command

Tags: networking, command-line, permissions

I tried installing gfortran through command line. And the result is

```
premkr@premkr-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD:~$ sudo wget gfortran
[sudo] password for premkr: 
--2016-10-29 01:07:36--  http://gfortran/
Connecting to 10.10.78.21:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2016-10-29 01:07:36 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

Does it mean that my terminal has no internet access .My proxy works in firefox and there`s good connection.

Comment: What makes you think that `sudo wget gfortran` should install gfortran? To install via commandline from the repository, you probably want `sudo apt-get install gfortran` or `sudo apt install gfortran`. If that's not what you're trying to do then please [edit] your question to explain further.

Comment: It`s not working                                                                                                               sudo apt install gfortran
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gfortran

Answer (score 0):

To have your terminal and wget have internet access through a proxy, you must edit the following files:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/environment
/etc/wgetrc
```

Which must contain these parameters:

/etc/bash.bashrc

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

/etc/environment

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

/etc/wgetrc:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
use_proxy = on
```

Edited 08-11-2016

To edit files, not directories, you must:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
nano /etc/bash.bashrc
nano /etc/environment
nano /etc/wgetrc
```

In order to add the aforementioned lines where:

```
username = your username for the proxy if it exists
password = your password for the proxy if it exists
proxyserver.net = name or IP address of the proxy
port = port number of the proxy
```

Comment: I don`t have the above directories. Should I create them? which text format should I use to write export "http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/" etc.

Comment: after I have written the command                                                                             "exec sudo -i
nano /etc/bash.bashrc"   a very long contents comes out. where should I put the username,password, proxyname etc.

Comment: http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
use_proxy = on                                                                                                                                                               these contents where found only in the /etc/wgetrc files which i editted and made active by removing #. Still i am unable to install anything through terminal or software centre